# Calling a java method in ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I am creating a jsp application in Netbeans Ide. I am having problems in calling a java class method in ajax.Is it possible to do so

My java class is something like this:

```
public class Hello
{
    public String execute(String s)
    {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to call the execute method using ajax :
My current ajax code is:

```
var val="test string";
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://localhost:8084/Shade/src/java/mail/Main.execute",
data: val,

async: true,
cache: false,
success: function (msg) {

alert("hi");
$(".col-1").html(msg);
});
```

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: Have a look over : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax/4113258#4113258)

Comment: Where is the Servlet? Java by itself does not provide HTTP connectivity, you must use a server/framework (Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss). All of them use the Servlet specification, your bussiness class must implement Servlet and be correctly declared in the server.

Comment: Or, instead of using Servlets, use SOAP (who manages the servlets for you). The first approach should be easier for a newcomer.

Comment: A method can be invoked via AJAX (JSON), if you use a RESTFul API like Spring or Struts. Otherwise, you have to send a request to a URL that responds with XML.

Answer (score 10):

`AJAX` is an acronym for `Asynchronous JavaScript And XML`. It provides an ability to communicate with the server asynchronously.

To explain that in simple terms, you can send a request to server and continue user interaction with the user. You need not wait for response from the server. Once the response arrives, a designated area in UI will update itself and reflect the response information. Whole page need not be reloaded.

So, you can not access Java Class directly as `url` to make your Ajax request. It should any mapped url like `JSP`, `Servlets`, `PHP` etc.

Create a JSP (e.g. `hello.jsp`)

```
<%
String strResponse;
mail.Main objMain = new mail.Main();
strResponse = objMain.execute();
%>

<%=strResponse %>
```

In Ajax request

```
url: "hello.jsp",
```

EDIT: Added Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      function getData() {
          var dataToBeSent  = {
            uName : $("#userName").val() , //
            passwd: $("#password").val()
            }; // you can change parameter name

          $.ajax({
                url : 'getDataServlet', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
                data :dataToBeSent, 
                type : 'POST',
                dataType : 'html', // Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.
                success : function(response) {
                    $('#outputDiv').html(response); // create an empty div in your page with some id
                },
                error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
      }

});
```

In Servlet/JSP access your parameters `request.getParameter("uName");`

Comment: @Baadshah: Thank You.. :). Can you please tell what's that ? So, I can edit.

Comment: :) I do not think you don't know may be you forgot.In order to use the java class file,we have to import that in jsp,right?

Comment: @Baadshah: As per OP's example I wrote `mail.Main` where `mail` is the package name. :)

Comment: thankyou. i just needed one thing more that how should i pass my variable data in ajax to my jsp file and hence to java method execute?

Comment: How we access `uName` in servlet, if `uName` passing in javascript is array object?  That is `var uName = [{id: 1, value: 'one'}, {id: 2, value: 'two'}];`. How we can access object variables too in servlet?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call the method directly. You should map an URL to the method you want to call.
This can be done in a servlet. If you're already serving pages through your Java code, you just add a new method to serve a page with the content you want.