# call the java method using ajax on button click

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I have a button in blank.jsp (lets say).

```
<input class="submit_button" type="submit" id="btnPay" name="btnPay" value="Payment" 
style="position: absolute; left: 350px; top: 130px;" onclick="javascript:payment();">
```

when button is clicked I need to call the java method callprocedure() using ajax.

```
function payment()
    {
        alert('Payment done successfully...');
        ........
        // ajax method to call java method "callprocedure()"
        ........
    }
```

I am new to ajax. how can we call the java method using ajax. Please help me soon.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been answered @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944000/calling-a-java-method-in-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove the inline onclick from the submit
2. add an onsubmit handler to the form
3. cancel the submission

I strongly recommend jQuery to do this especially when you have Ajax involved

I assume here the servlet function is in the form tag. If not, exchange `this.action` with your servlet name

```
$(function() {
  $("#formID").on("submit",function(e) { // pass the event
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel submission
    $.post(this.action,$(this).serialize(),function(data) {
      $("#resultID").html(data); // show result in something with id="resultID"
      // if the servlet does not produce any response, then you can show message
      // $("#resultID").html("Payment succeeded");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: i would like to know what's the differences your method and directly call ajax? I'm still learning ajax.. please advise... thanks a lot

Comment: Mine is much simpler (shortcut) and is not using the deprecated success/error

Answer (score 2):

try to use this method..

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '/servlet/yourservlet',
            success: function(result){
            // when successfully return from your java  
            }, error: function(){
               // when got error
            }
        });
```

Comment: That is quite inelegant and error and success have been replaced by fail and done

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks for your advice.. i m still learning ajax.. could you point out more detail? thanks..

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your `payment` is in a `servlet`.

All you need is this

```
function payment(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "yourServletURL",
        success: function(data){
            alert("Payment successful");
        },
        error: function (data){
            alert("sorry payment failed");
        }
    });
}
```