# how to call servlet page on jsp page load using js

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

When I called JSP page at that time java file or servlet file call using javascript.

I mean to say When JSP page load event java or servlet code execute.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: How to call java class

Comment: Take the top and bottom duplicate and mix

Comment: `window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){    function updateDB() {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "database/update.html", true);
      xhr.send(null);
      /* ignore result */
    } )}`

Comment: It's not working in Java ,Because how to call java class method

Comment: You mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944000/calling-a-java-method-in-ajax

Comment: yes, for example, add an item.jsp page load at that time item.java file and its method should be  called using ajax or js

Comment: read the LINKS!!!

Comment: But here not trusted answer.

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=Calling+a+java+method+in+aja

Comment: Your question as almost ZERO information. Please delete the question and come back with a researched and well defined question after reading the links I posted in my first comment. SO is not your private Google filter